# How else might the Latin 'torrere' have shifted semantically to mean 'rushing, roaring (of streams)'?

Tags: etymology

> [[Etymonline]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=torrent) [...] from Latin *torrentem* (nominative *torrens*) "rushing, roaring" (of streams), also "a rushing stream," originally as an adjective "roaring, boiling, burning, parching, hot, inflamed," present participle of *torrere* "to parch" (see [terrain](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=terrain&allowed_in_frame=0)).

Google revealed only [one conjecture](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:KDuAaVDUxb8J:mittani.blogspot.com/2009/06/notes-on-etymology-of-torrent.html+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us):

> So, what could be the connection between a rushing stream and something which is dried out, thirsting for some water?
>
> Supposedly, the contrasting meanings are linked by the image of a mountain creek or river which may be a raging current in spring, but dries out in summer.

I cannot diagnose why, but the above feels unconvincing, probably because:

1. most raging streams do not dry;
2. it is deceptive to describe a dried raging stream as a 'raging stream', because a stream is dried, if and only if, it is NOT raging. To wit, 'dry' and 'rushing, roaring' are polarly opposite adjectives if water is the underlying semantic notion.

I know that etymology is subjective and speculative, but are there any other conjectures of more conviction and common sense?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, this conexion between a dried-out creek and a torrent of water seems unlikely. The Proto-Indo-European root supposedly meant "make/be dry". De Vaan simply says that there may have been a stative present verb **trs-eh1-* "to be dried out" in Proto-Indo-European, from which a participle *torrens* "dry" logically followed.¹

The only etymological path that makes any sense to me would be dry → hot → flaming → raging with flames → raging → torrential. But that is quite the semantic distance to cross, and we need intermediate evidence.

---

¹) Michiel de Vaan, *Etymological Dictionary of Latin and the other Italic Languages* (Leiden 2008), s.v.